# Codeigniter return username based on id

Tags: php, mysql, function, codeigniter

I created a helper for returning a user's username if the user's unique id is known.

```
if ( ! function_exists('get_username'))
{
    function get_username($user_id)
    {
        $ci=& get_instance();
        $ci->load->database(); 

        if (empty($user_id))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $ci->db->select('username');
        $ci->db->where('id', $user_id);
        $ci->db->where('activated', 1);
        $ci->db->where('banned', 0);
        $ci->db->limit(1);
        $query = $ci->db->get('users');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) //if user exists
        {
            $row = $query->row();
            return $row->username;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

This works in my view if for instance I try:

```
echo get_username($this->uri->segment(3)); //uri segment 3 is a user id.
```

However want to send the username to my view via controller. I tried the following in my controller:

```
function write_message($user_id = '') //function parameter is 3rd uri segment
{
    $data['username'] = get_username($user_id);
    $this->load->view('my_view', $data);
}
```

Then in my view I have

`echo $username` which echoes `array` instead of the username. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the output of `<pre>print_r($username)</pre>` in your view?

Comment: Great question! Apparently I was echoing an array for an input with the same variable name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your criteria should be clear, and the usrname should be unique i think, so...

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) //if user exists, and unique
{
    $res = $query->result_array();
    return $res[0]['username'];
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon using `<pre>print_r($username)</pre>` in my view (as suggested by Alfonso) it was easy to spot the issue, being an identical variable name in my view which was another array. Correct answer goes to anyone that gives a good suggestion/input for my helper or Alfonso if he submits his post as answer.